# Programmatically attach an image to a field

Tags: nodes, media, 9

I am using Drupal 9.3.13 on localhost. I generate successfully a QR Code based on the .SVG format and store that image on public://. I  created various field types, one of which is a *field_file_svg* field type.

The goal is to attach that existing image uploaded to the public:// directory and attach it to field_file_svg. I am using `hook_entity_presave()` for this. The QR Code is generated and stored successfully, but the node doesn't show anything.

In /admin/reports/dblog/ it throws the following error.

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in urlist_entity_presave() (line 83 of C:\MAMP\htdocs\drupal9\modules\custom\urlist\urlist.module)

This the code I am using

```php
$qrcode = (new QRCode($options))->render("$output");
$file_data = file_get_contents($qrcode);
$file = file_save_data($file_data, 'public://t10.svg', FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);

if (!empty($file)) { 
  $file_arr = array(
    "target_id" => $file->id(),
    "alt" => "Alt1",
    "title" => "Title1"
  );       
   
  $node->field_file_svg = $file_arr;
}
```

Comment: This is not a Drupal issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900701/creating-default-object-from-empty-value-in-php

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, I do not get it. I am using PHP version: 7.4.1. The error is at $node->field_file_svg = $file_arr;. I do not understand what I should do.

Comment: @4uk4 Apache
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.1
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.4.1

Comment: This PHP warning means you are trying to set the field on an empty variable `$node`.

Comment: @4uk4 But how it's empty? I assign it with $node->field_file_svg = $file_arr; I'am confused.

Comment: @4uk4 I've used devel and I saw the structure of the field.

Comment: In a default \stdClass object?

Comment: @4uk4 I've used $node = new \stdClass();
        $node->success = false;
        $node->field_file_svg = $file_arr; with no errors in dblog. Still the image is generated succesfully, but does not get attached in the field.

Comment: I take this as a confirmation devel shows a stdClass object. This is not a node. You have to assign a node to $node first in order to set a field value to the node.

Comment: @4uk4 I'm really sorry, but I am new to Drupal. How can I do that? With $node = Node::load(1);

Comment: @4uk4 I've used dpm and print_r and I can see stdClass Object ( [success] => [field_file_svg] => Array ( [target_id] => 21 [alt] => Alt1 [title] => Title1 ) ) field_file_svg

Comment: @4uk4 I can see the field_file_svg in fieldDefinitions just fine, but not in the #values array in devel.